# HTML / CSS (possible :checked pseudo selector) visualization trouble with IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I am working on a homework from a software academy I study at.. the task is to make a simple gallery which should visualize the clicked thumbnail photo in a larger resolution. Somehow I got that done using radiobuttons in a form (correctly or not).. and the gallery works on most major borwsers just fine, except IE (of course)...

I've tried on IE9 and IE11 and it does not seems to work at all. Whatever you click on a thumbnail, nothing changes. I'd aprpeciate, if someone take a look at the code and give and advice what might be the problem.

Thank you in advance!

I have replaceed the images with random ones for the working example:

http://jsfiddle.net/J34VM/1/

```
img {
 position: relative;
}

#holder {
 width: 1075px;
 margin: 10px auto;
}

#holder form {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 position: relative;
}

label .thumb {
 width: 150px;
 height: 120px;
 opacity: 0.6;
}
label .thumb:hover {
 opacity: 1;
}
label .display {
 position: absolute;
 width: 860px;
 height: 688px;
 top: 130px;
 left: 10%;
 display: none;
}
input {
 display: none;
}
input:checked + label .thumb {
 opacity: 1;
}
input:checked + label .display {
 display: block;
}
li {
 display: inline;
 list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: it work for me ... on IE10

Comment: That's very confusing, as I have just realized that it  DOES work on my office computer, which is with IE9. Still, I've sent it to few other friends with IE 9 and IE11...and it DOES NOT work..and it DOES NOT work in my home, where I do have IE11 as well.... It is really weird...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem might be caused by the `display:none` of the radio button, the radio button might not get checked when it has `display:none` **(ONLY ON IE)**.

If that is the problem, try positioning your radio buttons away from the page rather than hiding them, replace this:

```
input {
    display: none;
}
```

with this:

```
input {
    position:absolute;
    left:-500px;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That is verry good thought, I will try that as soon as I can, thank you! I think another possible solution might be:                                    input {
    position:absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}

Comment: I think it should work but I can't test it because I have IE8 on my machine (which does not support the :checked pseudo selector :D)

Comment: Well, sadly this haven't changed a thing..still not working on some of  the IEs...

Answer (score 0):

Well,

after some investigation turns to be a well known IE bug with the so called - clickable lable. It simply does not check your radio, when you click on the associated label, when you have an img inside the label.

As I cannot use js for a workaround in my task I will have to seek anoher solution.

I thought it might be useful to share what I found so far.